# Split pandas dataframe by column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so :

```
id code mean count  

1   A    32    22  
1   B    9     56
1   C    25    78
2   A    33    35
2   B    11    66
```

Basically, for every ID there might be N number of entries and N varies for each ID, for some it might be 1, 2 for some it might be 3 or more. Keep in mind that for a pair of `(id, code)` there will be a single entry. In other words there is a single entry for each id for each code.

I want to split the csv by `code` so for every code I have a single `ID` entry and for each `code` I have a separate csv file housing the id, mean and count column.

Comment: Use `[g for _, g in df.groupby(['code'])]`

Comment: @jezrael Wow! can you please explain the syntax?

Comment: @SuhasMucherla - It is simlple iterate by groupby object in list comprehension.

Comment: @jezrael Nice :) Thanks josef!